# Creating a User who has-and-belongs-to-many existing Courses with a CakePHP form

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an app with two associated models: User and Course, which are related by a HABTM association.

There is a registration form where a new user may enter a username and select the courses that they are a part of (from a list of existing courses in the database), only the form only saves the new users - it doesn't save anything to the join table.

The join table (`courses_users`) has columns `course_id` and `user_id`, and the two models look like this:

```
// User.php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Courses' => array(
            'className' => 'Course',
            'joinTable' => 'courses_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associatedForeignKey' => 'course_id'
        )
    );
}

// Course.php
class Course extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Course';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Users' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'joinTable' => 'courses_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
            'associatedForeignKey' => 'user_id'
        )
    );
}
```

In addition, this is the controller action:

```
// IdentificationController.php
public function register() {
    if ($this->request->is('POST')) {
        $data = $this->request->data;
        $username = $data['User']['username'];

        $saved = $this->User->save($data, array('deep' => true));
        //debug($data);

        if ($saved) {
            $this->_set_new_user_session($username);

            //$log = $this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
            //debug($log);

            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'));
        }
    }

    // Not redirecting
    $courses = $this->Course->find('list', array('Course.name'));
    //debug($courses);
    $this->set(compact('courses'));
}
```

And this is the form, sans container divs:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'label' => false,
        'div' => false
    ),
    'url' => '/identification/register'
));

echo $this->Form->input('username', array(
    'error' => false,
    'autofocus' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'pattern' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,16}'
));

if ($this->Form->isFieldError('username')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('username', null, array('wrap' => 'small', 'class' => 'error'));
}

echo $this->Form->input('Course.Course', array(
    'error' => false,
    'required' => true
));

if ($this->Form->isFieldError('courses')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('course', null, array('wrap' => 'small', 'class' => 'error'));
}

echo $this->Form->button('Register', array(
    'div' => false,
    'type' => 'submit'
));

echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

When I call debug($data), the right data seems to be passed from the form to the controller:

```
array(
    'User' => array(
        'username' => 'test63apd'
    ),
    'Course' => array(
        'Course' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

But nothing happens to the join table, and there is no mention of the join table in the DataSource log:

```
array(
    'log' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'query' => 'BEGIN',
            'params' => array(),
            'affected' => null,
            'numRows' => null,
            'took' => null
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'query' => 'INSERT INTO `xray2`.`users` (`username`) VALUES ('test06apd')',
            'params' => array(),
            'affected' => (int) 1,
            'numRows' => (int) 1,
            'took' => (float) 1
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'query' => 'COMMIT',
            'params' => array(),
            'affected' => (int) 1,
            'numRows' => (int) 1,
            'took' => (float) 1
        )
    ),
    'count' => (int) 3,
    'time' => (float) 2
)
```

Am I missing something really obvious here, or is there some quirk of Cake that I have yet to discover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only telling Cake to save the primary model data. You need to change this line:-

```
$saved = $this->User->save($data, array('deep' => true));
```

To:-

```
$saved = $this->User->saveAssociated($data, array('deep' => true));
```

[`saveAssociated()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) tells Cake to save the current model and its associated data. You also shouldn't need to pass `array('deep' => true)` as you are only saving data to a directly associated model. So it would be better (and safer) to use:-

```
$saved = $this->User->saveAssociated($data);
```

**Update**

There is an issue with the data being saved as you are not using the alias defined in your association for the data. So when Cake attempts to save the associated data it can't see any. According to your code your `User` model has and belongs to many `Courses` (plural) but your save data uses `Course` (singular). Therefore, your form should be:-

```
echo $this->Form->input('Courses.Courses', array(
    'error' => false,
    'required' => true
));
```

It should be noted that [Cake naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) use singular forms for model names, so it would be better to use `Course` in the association rather than `Courses`. If you change this then your association can be simplified to the following:-

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Course'
);
```

Cake will understand how to handle the join table and foreign keys as they conform to the naming convention. Then you wouldn't need to change your form.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. I've tried this and it doesn't fix the problem. I'm really confused.

Comment: @JacobWalker have you tried looking at the SQL Cake is generating for the save? Your data looks good to me.

Comment: I've edited my initial question to add the DataSource log

Comment: @JacobWalker I've updated my answer. Your issue is with the alias being used for the HABTM association.

Comment: Thank you so much - this solved it. I do have to set a view variable called "courses" which contains the available courses (from find('all')), though. Is that a convention?

Comment: @JacobWalker yes, usually if you need to populate a form element (*e.g.* a `<select>`) you use the plural of the model name. However, this tends to be done with `find('list')` rather than `find('all')` as you want an array of name values indexed by the primary keys. Anyway, glad you're problem is solved. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: I have changed it to `find('list')` now. Thanks for your help!